# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve definition for form bean, Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

I have been working on a JSP Project. It uses Struts 1 framework. The project is old, I have many pages, so I decided to add a new one. I copied an existing page with all of its configs, models actions, so everything should be OK. But it is not!

I want to create a simple JSP file first. It was great without `<html:form>`, I saw my     "Hello World". Then I modified my file to this:

```
<% request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");%>
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-nested" prefix="nested"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fa" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/finearts"%>

<fa:checkLogon/>

<fa:Header/>
<fa:Navigation navigationId="806"/>

<html:form action="/pages/editTexts.do" method="post" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this);"     >
</html:form>
<fa:Footer/>
```

and got this error:

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /pages/editTexts.jsp at line 15**

```
12: <fa:Header/>
13: <fa:Navigation navigationId="806"/>
14: 
15: <html:form action="/pages/editTexts.do" method="post" onsubmit="return     doSubmit(this);" >
16: </html:form>
17: <fa:Footer/>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at depo.common.filter.EncodeFilter.doFilter(EncodeFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve definition for form bean: "EditTextsForm" on action: "/pages/editTexts.do"
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:852)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:781)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.editTexts_jsp._jspService(editTexts_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    ... 24 more

Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot retrieve definition for form bean:     "EditTextsForm" on action: "/pages/editTexts.do"
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.lookup(FormTag.java:881)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag.doStartTag(FormTag.java:488)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.editTexts_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f0(editTexts_jsp.java:170)
    at org.apache.jsp.pages.editTexts_jsp._jspService(editTexts_jsp.java:94)
    ... 27 more
create connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8create     connectionjdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/szepmubk?    relaxAutoCommit=true&autoReconnect=true&useServerPrepStmts=false&useUnicode=true&characterEn    coding=UTF-8&mysqlEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=UTF-8javax.servlet.ServletException:     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:520)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:427)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at depo.common.filter.EncodeFilter.doFilter(EncodeFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at depo.finearts.action.EditTextsAction.execute(EditTextsAction.java:35)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    ... 26 more
```

**EditTextsForm.java**

```
package depo.finearts.form;
import depo.common.db.DBConnection;
import depo.finearts.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class EditTextsForm extends ActionForm {
    DBConnection connection;
    User user;
    String action;
    int id;


    @Override
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
        if (!action.startsWith("validate") ) return null;
        setAction("save");
        return errors;
    }
    @Override
    public void reset( ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super.reset(mapping, request);
        try {
          setConnection(new DBConnection());
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null || "".equals(action)) {
            action = "invalid";
        }
        if (request.getParameterMap().containsKey("id")) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
            user = new User(connection, id);
        } else {
            user = new User(connection);
        }
    }
    public void save () throws Exception {
        getUser().save();
        getConnection().getConnection().commit();
    }

    public DBConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void setConnection(DBConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**config**

```
<action
    path="/pages/edit*"
    type="depo.finearts.action.Edit{1}Action"
    name="Edit{1}Form"
    scope="request"
    validate="true"
    input="/pages/edit{1}.jsp?action=invalid">
    <forward name="form" path="/pages/edit{1}.jsp" />      
    <forward name="view" path="/pages/view{1}.jsp" />                        
</action>
```

Comment: do you get any other errors like NullPointer? why is `onsubmit="return doSubmit(this);"` in your code?

Comment: It should show you really specific who caused the error (`NullPointerException`, etc.). When you get it, update your question please.

Comment: Do you have a `<html:html>` "embracing" all tags? If not, try adding one, and a `<body>` as well.

Comment: 1. there was a validation script in the other file, but I removed it and got the same error.
2. If I open editTexts.do, then I got blank page with NullPointerException (My opinion is, the processing action gets ActionForm form as null). If I open editTexts.jsp, then I got the error I updated now.

Comment: do you have a form bean called "EditTextsForm" at all?
are you sure that the JDBC connection is setup properly?
show class and config-files if you have any...

Comment: 3. If I use editUser.do as action (it was the file, that i copied), it works well! So I guess I have all tags emraced. The error must be because of the action method of html:form :( But I dont know why

Comment: I updated with EditTextsForm and the part of the config

Comment: is that all in your config-file?

Comment: <form-bean name="EditTextsForm" type="depo.finearts.form.EditTextsForm"/> it was missing from the config file :) It seems to be working now, you are great :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. check whether you have defined this frombean with this name "EditTextsForm" in  tag of struts-config.xml

Comment: Je, this was the problem :) @ClydeFrog successfully helped me